# title of anchor shows text till single quote (') while concatenating string

Tags: c#

while concatenating string in .cs, title of anchor shows till the single quote(') remained text gets skipped

```
string tempText = "He hasn't returned my call.";
html = string.Concat(html, "<a  title=" + tempText + ">hello</a>");
```

output: He hasn

Comment: make sure your code can be compiled without an error.

Comment: @kennyzx I updated my code and it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML Encoding:

```
string tempText = "He hasn't returned my call.";
string htmlEnc = Server.HtmlEncode(tempText); 
html = string.Concat(html, "<a  title=" + htmlEnc + ">hello</a>");
```

More info: https://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode

Answer (score 2):

You just forget to put `"` on title attribute :

```
string tempText = "He hasn't returned my call.";
html = string.Concat(html, "<a  title=\"" + tempText + "\">hello</a>");
```

Comment: It's still a good idea to add HTML escaping, so that there is no problem when the tempText contains double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing to add quotes to the HTML tag parameter. Make this change to add quote characters at the beginning and end of the parameter value:

```
string tempText = "He hasn't returned my call.";
html = string.Concat(html, "<a  title=\"" + tempText + "\">hello</a>");
```

Additionally, all text you put into HTML should go through HTML escaping so that

1 you don't have syntax problems

2 Security problems that arise from an attacker embedding html syntax into an input string are prevented

```
string tempText = "He hasn't returned my call.";
html = string.Concat(html, "<a  title=\"" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tempText) + "\">hello</a>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear but if you want to encode a single quote for display in a webpage you should use `&apos;`

```
string tempText = "He hasn&apos;t returned my call."; html = string.Concat(html, "hello");
```